# scrapy is using HTTP 1.0 by default

Tags: python, scrapy

It looks like Scrapy is using HTTP 1.0 by default. Is there a setting to make it use HTTP 1.1 to send request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

From http://dev.scrapy.org/wiki/ScrapyRecipes:

How to spoof requests to be HTTP 1.1 compliant
You can do this by overriding the Scrapy HTTP Client Factory, with the following (undocumented) setting:

```
DOWNLOADER_HTTPCLIENTFACTORY = 'myproject.downloader.HTTPClientFactory'
```

Here's a possible implementation of myproject.downloader module:

```
from scrapy.core.downloader.webclient import ScrapyHTTPClientFactory, ScrapyHTTPPageGetter

class PageGetter(ScrapyHTTPPageGetter):

    def sendCommand(self, command, path):
        self.transport.write('%s %s HTTP/1.1\r\n' % (command, path))

class HTTPClientFactory(ScrapyHTTPClientFactory):

    protocol = PageGetter
```